# AS3 new BitmapData(w,h); gets ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid, works for a while then stops with this error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

I have a game that produces new chunks of terrain as the player explores, to allow for a seemingly unlimited level size. It's been working perfectly, but I decided to let my character travel in one direction for a long time, and eventually it gets this error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.
        at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()
        at flash.display::BitmapData()
```

At this line of code:

```
this.new_chunk.background_bitmap_data = new BitmapData(this.level_obj.block_size *  this.new_chunk.blocks_wide + this.level_obj.oversize_bmd_offset,this.level_obj.block_size * this.new_chunk.blocks_tall + this.level_obj.oversize_bmd_offset,true,0x00000000);
```

I ran a `trace();` on the variables/equations that provide the width and height values being used to create the bitmap data, and it outputs the same values constantly, as intended:

```
2150 1300
```

I ran my character in a number of different directions, and the same thing eventually happens regardless of direction. I know that the `BitmapData` isn't getting too large, because it's always 2150x1300.

Note:  The error does not occur while staying in a small area, no matter how long I leave the game running, the error only occurs after traveling in one direction for a long time, generating numerous new chunks of level.

Any ideas why flash is throwing this error?

### EDIT:

Here is a live demo of the game so you can get a better understanding of what's going on:
http://test.webskethio.com/boxy/

(Controls are W.A.S.D for movement, hold shift to move faster.)

Each "chunk" is the size of the game screen itself, each chunk stores a cached `BitmapData` of all of the smaller `BitmapData`s that make it up (the tiles of grass, trees, rocks, flowers, etc.) The chunk `BitmapData` is loaded to a `Bitmap` on the stage when the chunk is close enough to the stage that it can end up needing to be rendered.

### EDIT 2:

I've uploaded a picture to illustrate what I believe is Amy's proposed method of rendering for my game that doesn't require the storage of many BitmapData objects:

[image]

The four corner colored areas are `BitmapData` objects that will be drawn to the one `Bitmap` on the screen (same size as the user's screen, represented in green.)  The black area around the whole thing represents what at one point could have been other `BitmapData` objects which have been set to `null` since they are no longer needed.

The 4 corner BitmapData objects will be redrawn to the main `Bitmap` with new point coordinates as the player moves.

Comment: What's different between staying in a small area and whatever else you might be doing that isn't staying in a small area? And why do you need that many new BitmapData instances anyway?

Comment: It's a game in which you have the freedom to travel wherever you want, in any direction. The game engine generates new chunks of terrain whenever it needs to so that you don't just run through empty space. The large BitmapData from the code above is how the game stores the 800+ tiles per chunk without having to have 800+ bitmaps on the stage. That many new BitmapData instances are necessary to allow the player complete freedom to go wherever they want.

Comment: You sure? Why couldn't you just draw() or copyPixels() to the same however many instances?

Comment: copyPixels to what? the BitmapData is what I'm copyPixeling to...

Comment: What X / Y does this occur at? Is it always the same X / Y? Also, do garbage disposal e.g if a BM is out of the screen, delete it. Re-instance only when necessary.

Comment: If the BitmapData is what you're copying pixels to, why do you need a new one? Why can't you just copy over the pixels you already have? Since you're creating so many, are you calling dispose() on the ones you're no longer using?

Comment: The pixels being copied to the main screen `BitmapData` object have to come from somewhere. In my case they come from a `BitmapData` object that has been composed carefully by a level chunk generation algorithm. In this way, there will always need to be new BitmapDatas being created during gameplay as long as the player explores new territory. It's faster to pre-render the new chunk to its own `BitmapData` and draw that to the main screen's `Bitmap` than it is to repeatedly re-copyPixel hundreds of objects to the screen every frame as the character moves. And yes, I am calling `dispose()`

Comment: @AmyBlankenship And besides, the error isn't being caused by a lack of memory, as I have 16GB of RAM, 13-14 of which are free at the time of running the game. The game errors out around 500mb to 1.5gb of memory usage , still leaving me with 11.5 - 13.5 GB of RAM free.

Comment: I'm pretty sure copyPixels is faster than draw(), and instantiation is one of the most expensive things you can do. Just sayin'

Comment: I'm using the word "draw" as a verb, the computer is drawing something to the screen, I only use the `copyPixel()` method, I do not use `draw()` except for when instantiating completely new `BitmapData` from images in the library, which only occurs during the loading phase at the beginning of the game. We've all still completely been ignoring my actual question, which is why I'm getting the bug I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce your error.

I was running straight north with shift for around 5 minutes, memory consumption grown to 3+GiB and then I got out of RAM so it started to use swap and got very slow.

So, I guess you just run out of memory, and the error of flash is a bit weird for that case. Try freeing old bitmaps, or maybe even better reusing it. The recommended approach is usually having 4 bitmaps of the size of the screen at all times, reusing west ones for new regions at east when you go east, vice verse and same for north and south.

Also, I see a very annoying blinking white stripe. I dont know if that's actually the reason, but it usually happens when someone don't use double-buffering.

Comment: Perhaps it's a flash version specific bug then, because I can only get RAM usage up to about 500MB before it crashes, and I have 16GB of RAM avaialable. I do plan to use the method you described with only the 4 screen sized bitmaps.

Comment: Honestly, you do NOT need 4 Bitmaps for this. Check out this example http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2012/06/endless-scrolling-bathroom.html . When you change from going east/west to North/south, you'd simply have to composite two source north or south images together to fill a rectangle that was growing upwards or downwards in the existing bitmap.

Comment: I don't completely understand the way you imagine it being done, but I assume you are haven't actually read the question or tried the demo. Using 4 buffers for this is a well-known method used in game industry for years and it's easy to calculate it's the most computation(render) effective for scenes with highly-dynamic(yet with dx per tick << width for the most part of ticks) viewport, yet have uses only 4 times more memory than most memory-effective(yet completely useless with any dynamics of viewport) method.

Comment: However, from reading your blogpost I understand that you are maybe talking about moving along only one axis.

Comment: @stroncium This is not an out-of-memory issue, as I have around 14GB of RAM available, and the game crashed out around 600MB of usage. I updated the game to erase bitmapdata that is no longer at risk of being on screen (more than 1 zone away from the active screen), and the error stopped happening at 600MB and started happening at 1.5GB.  I suspect this is a flash version specific, or even hardware specific problem, as you guys seem to not be experiencing it.

Comment: @stroncium In response to Amy's assertion and referenced blog post:   You're right, I can make this game work with only one Bitmap, although I don't see why 4 bitmaps is a problem either. However, I've uploaded [an image to illustrate what I think you're talking about, and what I now plan to do.](http://i.imgur.com/t9XZP.png)

Comment: @JonathonG Yep, you got it right. Also, every game can actually do with one bitmap, it's just a matter of optimization(quite useful when you go with flash which is a bit slower than good old pure C). Also, if you expect screen in your game to be "shaking" by some small amount of pixels it would also be good to make this offscreen bitmaps that amount of pixels larger, so you wont be experiencing render time spikes when such shaking happens around position exactly matching corner of offscreen(Which would normally lead to redraws of  2-3 offscreens on every "shaking" frame.).

Comment: Also, I examined Amy's blogpost again, and I guess I managed to get the point. As far as I understand, she talks about cyclic scrolling backgrounds. For them, one offscreen is really enough. Another thing I wanted to mentioned is a text from your pic. One of the key features of my(not my really) approach is that you need just 4 offscreens, as variables. No arrays/sparcearrays/hashes, no nullifying pointers = no chances of memory leaks. Actually, you dont even need any memory allocations after allocating screenbuffer, doublebuffer(if used) and this 4 offscreens.